# Why EditText keeps moving window up when newline is typed

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText that makes the activity window experience "ride up" :(

I don't know how to embed the video correctly, it's at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qqDY6Bw2s4

It allows multiline height up to 5 lines. If the text starts less than 5 lines, when you tap on it and start adding lines, the window shifts up with every line. Not just the first 5. It keeps going with *every* new line. It will even shift the EditText up off the screen (not shown in video).

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/bio"
            android:layout_columnSpan="@integer/edit_profile_columns"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:background="#e5e5e5"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:maxLength="@{Config.maxBioLength}"
            android:text="@={userProfile.bio}"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:textSize="@dimen/editprofile_edittext_textsize"
            tools:text="jkfgsdfasdffdssdfkh dsf"
            />
```

And it's inside a GridLayout, as you may have guessed.

```
<GridLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
         android:paddingTop="10dp"
         android:paddingBottom="30dp"
         android:columnCount="@integer/edit_profile_columns"
         android:useDefaultMargins="false"
         android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
         android:theme="@style/EditProfileOverlay"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
         >
```

[image: Screenshot with layout bounds requested by comenter]

Comment: how many columns did you set on the grid layout? If you want the edittext to go full width, you should assign it a column span equal to the amount of columns that exist in your grid layout.

Comment: Also, If you can take another screenshot of the app with the layout bounds in your settings activated, I could probably tell you what's wrong. Just go to settings, developer options and activate show layout bounds.

Comment: You could kind of bodge it by using `maxHeight`

Comment: @JavierVentajasHernández to the first comment, you can see that is the case with the `layout_columnSpan` and `columnCount` attributes

Comment: For the time being, if I remove `maxLines="5"` then the issue becomes acceptable, arguably correct. It seems like the window panning logic doesn't take the view's maxLines into account. There is also the issue of having to support nested scroll with the maxLines, so for now I will use that workaround

Comment: I don't know if I understood the question completely, but I think what you want is the edittext to not change size every time you add a line, right? To accomplish that you can set the property lines=5 and minLines=5 to the edittext. That way, you will avoid sudden changes in height. Let me know if this is what you are trying to do, otherwise I'll reply with a new suggestion.

Comment: I've narrowed down the bug. Suppose I put just `android:lines="5"`. Now you think there would be no scroll issue on this view. BUT. If you trigger the keyboard _while EditText is not fully visible_, then Android will bump up the view to be fully visible, _and also keep scrolling up the activity with each newline_. However, now try summoning the keyboard with the EditText fully visible. Android never scrolls the activity whether you add or delete lines. Why? I haven't tried to reproduce outside of GridView, but this seems like a bug. Can I just detect the keyboard summon and scroll the view?

Answer (score 0):

I reported this here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=264055

In the simpler case, the ride up happens no matter where the view is before opening the keyboard.